# Why Apple suggests use your own NSFileManager when you use NSFileManagerDelegate?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

In apple docs of `defaultManager` they say:

> This method always returns the same file manager object. If you plan to use a delegate with the file manager to receive notifications about the completion of file-based operations, you should create a new instance of NSFileManager (using the init method) rather than using the shared object.

I just want to know that why they suggest to use a new instance of NFileManager when you use a delegate of the file manager?What's wrong if I use the shared file manager to do this?

The only thing I can see is that your delegate object will receive a lot of notifications that you don't want to know, is anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last paragraph is pretty much it. If you set the delegate on the shared file manager, your delegate ends up getting called way more than you want. By creating a specific instance of `NSFileManager` and setting that instance's `delegate`, then you know the delegate methods are only being called for that specific use of the file manager and not all of the default uses.

Keep in mind that the default file manager instance could be used by a lot more than your own code. Lots of other libraries and frameworks will be using it as well.